# How to consolidate multiple similar functions into a single one?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I'm stuck on a piece of JavaScript code that applies an event on the Youtube API. The goal is when you click on the appropriate button, the video moves backwards by 5s, 10s or 30s or advances by 5s, 10s or 30s.

My problem is that I have six functions that are alike but do not have the same time values. (in this example I put only two of the functions: `rewind5()` to back up 5 seconds and `rewind10()` to back up 10 seconds).

I am looking for a charitable soul that could help me to combine these two functions (`rewind5()` and `rewind10()`) into a single function. Once I have the right structure I could create the four other functions using the single function.

My JS file :

```
// Rewind 5s

function onPlayerReady(event){
    if(player.getPlayerState()===1 || player.getPlayerState()===2){
        $('#s5back').prop('disabled', false);
        $( '#s5back' ).click(function() {
            rewind5();
            });
    } else {
        $('#s5back').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}

function rewind5() {
    var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
    player.seekTo(currentTime - 5, true);
    player.playVideo();

};

// Rewind 10s

function onPlayerReady(event){
    if(player.getPlayerState()===1 || player.getPlayerState()===2){
        $('#s10back').prop('disabled', false);
        $( '#s10back' ).click(function() {
            rewind10();
            });
    } else {
        $('#s10back').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}

function rewind10(){
    var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
    player.seekTo(currentTime - 10, true);
    player.playVideo();
};
```

My HTML file :

```
<div id="video-placeholder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var player,
time_update_interval = 0;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        width: '100%',
        height: '625px',
        videoId: 'ID URL YOUTUBE',
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            controls: 0,
            rel: 0,
            showinfo: 0
        },
        events: {
            onReady: initialize,
            onStateChange: onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have just a single `seekBy` function, and pass it the desired number of seconds to rewind?

```
function seekBy(secs){
  var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
  player.seekTo(currentTime + secs, true);
  player.playVideo();
}
```

and implement it with, for example

```
$('#s10back').click(function() {
  seekBy(-10);
});
```

or 5 seconds, or 30, or 60. To go forward, pass a positive number instead:

```
$('#s10forward').click(function() {
  seekBy(10);
});
```

Comment: Sure, just pass it a positive or negative argument. Better to rename it something other than `rewind` then

Comment: You wrote that answer faster than me :) @SMIIILE you pass negatives numbers to the function to rewind, positives to move forward

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you a lot :)